# How can I change gcc in Xcode to 4.9 installed via MacPorts ('type_traits' file not found)

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am using the latest Xcode and I am trying to get pass an error. The error is the following:

> action_dispatch.hpp:21:10: 'type_traits' file not found

I searched the internet for answers, but I couldn't find any relevant info. From the topics which were related to my error suggested to get the latest gcc and add that to Xcode.

Can anybody tell me how to set this in Xcode or how to get pass that error message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: XCode 4.6.2 seems to include that file without a hitch with LLVM chosen as a compiler.

Comment: How can I check which gcc runs under Xcode? I will try what you suggested. This means that I have to change in Project>>Build settings>>Compiler for C/C++... to LLVM GCC? Because there I have only LLVM GCC 4.2.

Comment: I'm using Apple LLVM 4.2, with C++ Language Dialect=GNU++11 and Standard Library libc++.

Comment: I have the same set up, except I have to use libstdc++, tho if I set these to Compiler default, and I remove a linker flag (-std=c++0x), then the error dismisses and compiles successfully!